# How to calculate ad(X)?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have looked everywhere, and maybe its really simple, and I am just being stupid, but I really don't know how to calculate ad(X). I understand that ad_x(y)=[x,y], but i just want to calculate ad(x)? I also know that Ad(g)(X) = g^(-1)*X*g. "g inverse multiplied by X multiplied by g", but the determinant for my g is 0, so it can't have an inverse, hence why I can't do it this way.
My g is \begin{bmatrix}0&x&y\\x&0&z\\y&-z&0\end{bmatrix}And I have to work out ad(x1), where x1 is one of the basis of the g. I already have the basis, it is \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adjoint operators ${\rm ad}(x)$ for $x\in L$ are *linear maps*, so we can compute them by evaluating them on a basis of the Lie algebra $L$. For example, let $L$ be the Heienberg Lie algebra with basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and brackets $[e_1,e_2]=e_3$. Then
$$
{\rm ad}(e_1)=\begin{pmatrix}
    0&0&0  \\
    0&0&0  \\
    0&1&0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
since ${\rm ad}(e_1)(e_2)=[e_1,e_2]=e_3$. The images of the basis vectors are the colums of the matrix.
Similarly for ${\rm ad}(e_2)$. Finally ${\rm ad}(e_3)=0$, since $e_3$ generates the center of $L$, and $Z(L)=\ker(ad(L))$.

For your Lie algebra, you first have to fix a basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$, then compute all Lie brackets, and from them write down the adjoint operators.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I calculated the lie brackets, they are: $[x_1,x_2] = x_3, [x_1,x_3] = x_2, [x_2,x_3] = -x_1$. I understand that $ad(x_1)(x_2) = [x_1,x_2] = x_3$, and similar to the other two, but I still don't know how to compute $ad(x_3)$? Thank you

Comment: Well, what is $ad(x_3)(x_i)$ for $i=1,2,3$? Then put the results as columns, see my answer.

Comment: $ad(x_3)(x_1) = -x_2, ad(x_3)(x_2) = x_1, ad(x_3)(x_3) = 0$, but how did you get the single $ad(x_1)$ or $ad(x_2)$ or $ad(x_3)$? Sorry it probably is really simple, I just still can't understand it. How did you put it in columns, such that how is $$
{\rm ad}(e_1)=\begin{pmatrix}
    0&0&0  \\
    0&0&0  \\
    0&1&0
\end{pmatrix},
$$ Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: $-x_2$ in this basis is $(0,-1,0)$, namely $0\cdot x_1+(-1)\cdot x_2+0\cdot x_3$. etc. Just linear algebra. You are welcome (upvote would be nice).

Comment: I totally understand that, so for your first example, with $[e_1,e_2] = e_3$, that is $(0,0,1)$, right? But how do you know to put it in the middle column, is it the $e_2$ that tells you this. For example, for the $ad(e_1)(e_3) = [e_1,e_3] = e_2$, then this would be $(0,1,0)$ and so, $$
{\rm ad}(e_1)=\begin{pmatrix}
    0&0&0  \\
    0&0&1  \\
    0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},
$$ Also, I tried to upvote but it doesnt let me, your post was much more helpful than the other one, sorry about that

Comment: I'll tick it as correct answer if that helps if I just understand this final part. Thank you a lot however for your help.

Comment: Actually I understand it now, to get the final matrix you have to add all the corresponding matrix (vector columns) together. Example, $ad(x_1)(x_2) = x_3, ad(x_1)(x_3) = x_2, ad(x_1)(x_1) = 0$, which means $x_3 = (0,0,1), x_2 = (0,1,0), 0 = (0,0,0)$ Thank you, so simple now, I just didn't know you have to include all three of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know structure constants in the base you're using, then the coefficients of the adjoint action are easily computed as
$$(ad(e_i))^k_j=c_{ij}^k,$$
since
$$ad(e_i)(e_j)=[e_i, e_j]=\sum{c_{ij}^k}e_k.$$